# if something = false display ads

Tags: android

i have a protected boolean as follows

```
protected boolean isKeyInstalled(Context context) {
          // the packagename of the 'key' app
          String proPackage = "com.funhouse.mytimmieskey";

          // get the package manager
          final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

          // get a list of installed packages
          List<PackageInfo> list = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_DISABLED_COMPONENTS);

          // let's iterate through the list
          Iterator<PackageInfo> i = list.iterator();
          while(i.hasNext()) {
            PackageInfo p = i.next();
            // check if proPackage is in the list AND whether that package is signed
            //  with the same signature as THIS package
            if((p.packageName.equals(proPackage)) &&
               (pm.checkSignatures(context.getPackageName(), p.packageName) == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH))
              return true;
          }
          return false;
        }
```

I'm trying to get it to show ads if false

```
if(isKeyInstalled(null) != false){
            //AdMob Banner
            LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adveiw);
            AdView ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14db2c31f42ef0");
            parent.addView(ad);
            AdRequest r = new AdRequest();
            r.setTesting(false);
            ad.loadAd(r);
        }
```

i have no code errors but this keeps cashing my app.

here is logcat

```
05-11 00:18:37.253: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.funhouse.mytimmies/.TimsMain bnds=[125,410][235,528] }
05-11 00:18:37.433: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Start proc com.funhouse.mytimmies for activity com.funhouse.mytimmies/.TimsMain: pid=1225 uid=10030 gids={3003}
05-11 00:18:37.814: DEBUG/ddm-heap(1225): Got feature list request
05-11 00:18:38.944: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1225): Shutting down VM
05-11 00:18:38.964: WARN/dalvikvm(1225): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
05-11 00:18:38.974: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.funhouse.mytimmies/com.funhouse.mytimmies.TimsMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at com.funhouse.mytimmies.TimsMain.isKeyInstalled(TimsMain.java:76)
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at com.funhouse.mytimmies.TimsMain.onCreate(TimsMain.java:27)
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
05-11 00:18:39.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1225):     ... 11 more
05-11 00:18:39.095: INFO/Process(52): Sending signal. PID: 1225 SIG: 3
```

Comment: Please show us the stack trace.

Comment: You're passing a null to your `isKeyInstalled` and you're getting a NullPointerException from that method.  It even tells you which line is throwing the NullPointerException.  Try following the null you pass in through your code and see where it goes.  Hint: if you attempt to call a method on some variable that's null, you'll get a NullPointerException.

Comment: I recommend to learn debugging. An NPE is pretty easy to find with that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();`is line 76 where your error is occuring, as the context you are passing is null...it's unable to start the Activity since the error is occuring in the onCreate method...pass in `this` (being your activity) as the context and it'll fix your problem.

Comment: I understand that a null is being passed. I have been trying many ways to get this to work but keep getting the same null error. what do you mean by pass in `this` (being your activity) as the context and it'll fix your problem? something like `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState,TimsMain context)`?

Comment: As in if(isKeyInstalled(null) != false)...that's where you're passing in a null context...it should be (isKeyInstalled(this) != false)

Comment: ah thank you still learning, I'm glad there are people willing to help.